# How to send text to the username field using Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to send information to a textfield and I am having difficulties locating it. There are multiple elements with the same name and it's difficult to find it.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="username">LDAPTEST Username</label>
  <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control top" title="This field is required." autofocus="autofocus" data-qa-selector="username_field" required="required">
  <p class="gl-field-error hidden">This field is required.</p> 
</div>
```

I have tried the following:

```
username_By = By.id("username")

username_By = By.cssSelector("input[data-qa-selector='username_field']")
```

I am getting TimeoutException when I am waiting for the visibility of the element.

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(username_By));
```

Any suggestions on how to locate the element? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

//label[contains(text(),'LDAPTEST Username')] Please use this xpath to locate elements to send keys

Answer (score 0):

It is a *username* field possibly you intent to send some text to the desired field. So to send a character sequence to the *LDAPTEST Username* field, instead of `visibilityOfElementLocated()` you need to use [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input.form-control.top#username[name='username']"))).sendKeys("anibal-bojorquez");
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@class='form-control top' and @id='username'][@name='username']"))).sendKeys("anibal-bojorquez");
  ```

---

### Update

Try the following alternatives:

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("label[for='username']"))).sendKeys("anibal-bojorquez");
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//label[@for='username']"))).sendKeys("anibal-bojorquez");
  ```

Comment: TimeoutException was thrown, waiting for element to be clickable

Comment: @anibal-bojorquez Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: I tried both cssSelector and xpath and I am still getting the TimeoutException

Comment: Hovering over the textfield it says input#username.form-control.top